# path is stored in data base now play it by click how to do it

Tags: android

i have store the path of song in database by retriving the song from sd card and then store that path in database. the listview is created that shows all the songs in the database now i want to play them by clicking on them. how to do it?

Thankx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create MediaPlayer object and set it's data source to your path. Something like this:

```
MediaPlayer songPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
try {
    songPlayer.setDataSource("path/to/song.mp3");
    songPlayer.prepare();
    songPlayer.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```